# What is the equivalent of Python's encode() in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, encode

I am transferring a Python script to Ruby.

The python method 'encode()' is used often. Examples:

```
apikey.encode()
encoded_payload = json.dumps(payload).encode()
```

It looks like the Ruby equivalent has a few required params that need to be added. UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1. Which one matches the standard python encode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby:

```
   string = "some string".encode
   string.encoding
```

> Encoding:UTF-8

So Ruby's [default](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Encoding.html) is UTF-8

Pythons [default](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/encode) also encodes in UTF-8

So no parameters to add, both defaults are the same: UTF-8

---

*For completeness*:

If someone want to change the default `UTF-8` you can do it in python (see [documentary](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/encode) and [supported encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)) by:

```
string.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
```

The same is in [Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Encoding.html):

`string.encode("UTF-8")`

Supported Ruby [encodings](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Encoding#Encoding_Support)

Comment: [`String#encode`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-encode) doesn't default to UTF-8: _The last form returns a copy of `str` transcoded to `Encoding.default_internal`._

Answer (score 0):

Python's [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) defaults to utf-8, so go with that.